# FullCalendar refetchEvents Cannot read property 'format' of null

Tags: php, jquery, events, fullcalendar, typeerror

When i am trying to refetch the events from Fullcalendar after a save i get the below error in fullcalendar.min.js:6.
Why am i getting this error?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'format' of null
```

I am using events as a json feed:

```
events: './scripts/events.php?user_id='+user_id,
```

Comment: The Object on which `format` is called is undefined. There is something wrong with the call you are making while using fullCalender

Comment: Can you provide sample event data returned from json feed? It seems, the start or end value of event object may be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this same error message and I solved this.

In my code problem was that on the page load my calendar div container was hide. I was need to show this calendar on click of a button, so on page load I have set calendar div container to showing, and after page load complete hide that container.

Comment: That is the solution that helped me. Good job figuring it out.

Comment: When your page is loading, you need to code for calendar container to be visible on page at time of fetching events after complete fetching you can hide that container.